# connect Xamarin app registration page to azure database for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I am trying to build a Xamarin mobile application and want to use Azure database for MySQl as database for the application.

I have already created the design for my registration page.
Need help on how to create an Azure database for MySQl and how to connect my application with it.
I have read that an API is needed to connect the app and the database.
Could not find any example on the internet that would show how to do all the above.

RegistrationPage.XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VeggiesUI.Views.RegistrationPage"
              Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Title="Registration"
             BackgroundImageSource="OIP.jpg">

    <StackLayout Margin="20,30,20,0" >
        
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter First Name"
                MaxLength="30" 
                Margin="5,0,5,10"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter Last Name"
               MaxLength="30" 
               Margin="5,0,5,10"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter Email"
               MaxLength="30" 
               Margin="5,0,5,10"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter Password"
               MaxLength="15" 
               Margin="5,0,5,10"/>

        <Entry Placeholder="Confirm Password"
               MaxLength="15" 
               Margin="5,0,5,5"/>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.10*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.90*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text=" Accept Ts and Cs."
                   Margin="0,5,5,0"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
            <Button Text="Register"
                        Clicked="OnSaveButtonClicked" 
                        BackgroundColor="LightGreen" 
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Margin="0,10,5,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="Clear"
                        BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Clicked="OnDeleteButtonClicked"
                        Margin="0,10,5,0"/>
        </Grid>

        <Button Text="Login Instead"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                TextColor="Blue"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                BorderWidth="0"
                CornerRadius="0"
                WidthRequest="150"
                FontSize="Medium"
                />

    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

RegistrationPage.XAML.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace VeggiesUI.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistrationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OnDeleteButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Xamarin and Azure.

Solution content

[image]

Answer (score 0):

· First create the Azure Mobile Service (database, server and table with desired backend language)

· Make sure you add the Azure Mobile SDK package in your project.

· Have an itemTable.cs class to define the properties of the object you want to add in your database

· Define a Itemservice.cs file in which you add all interaction of the application with the Azure Mobile Service

For more information follow this article [How to build a Xamarin App connected to Azure - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/how-to-build-a-xamarin-app-connected-to-azure/ba-p/379338)

Comment: Hi Abhishek, there is no mobile app on the portal.

Comment: Azure Mobile Service has been deprecated and replaced with Azure Mobile Apps https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/